# Assign data to a string

Tags: powershell

When I type `Get-Process` in PowerShell, I get this:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
   1056      15     2952       1844    49   124.29    580 csrss
   1158      78    63620      42976   356   593.47   5784 explorer
```

Is there a way I can concatenate all the data from row 1 onto string 1, and row 2 onto string 2, etc.

For example:

```
$str1 = "csrss 580 124.29 49 ..."
$str2 = "explorer 5784 593.47 356 ..."
```

Comment: Why, though? What are you going to do with those strings? You may want `Export-Csv -Delimiter` instead. You *can* force the objects into strings, but you'll lose out on a ton of flexibility. Compare `(Get-Process)[0]`, `(Get-Process)[0].ProcessName`, `Get-Process | Foreach { $_.ProcessName + " " + $_.ID }`. As long as they're objects, you can manipulate them any way you want. A string is a string.

Comment: What Jeroen said. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need these individual strings for?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine each line fairly easily using a foreach loop.

```
$processes = Get-Process
$processes | % {[string[]]$processLines += $_.ProcessName + "," + $_.Id}
$processLines
```

The above code will give you an array of strings for each process. You will have to decide what properties you want to include on each string. If you want to create separate variable names instead of using an array that would require a bit more work.